# Metacryptic ep. 3

Tags: cryptic-clues

Solve the cryptic clues below to create the final clue. Solve the final clue.

1. Sick inside broken seats causes amputation (8)
2. Fowl gets drunk barside (7)
3. Chaotic print aped captured preposition (7, 2)
4. Endless instances malfunction (9)
5. Center of Liechtenstein and Nicaragua's lovely sport (6)
6. Play tune with two helpings of rosemary, first get refund (6)
7. Dubois has woven silk (3)

(8)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

4. Endless instances malfunction (9)

> INCESSANT ("endless" as def, anagram of "instances")

6. Play tune with two helpings of rosemary, first get refund (6)

> RETURN ("tune" plus two helpings of R as "rosemary first", "play" indicates anagram, and "refund" as def)

**Metacryptic** (making use of clues solved by [Silenus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47846/5373) and [Will](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47848/5373)):

> Tailless seabird trapped in incessant tennis return web (8)

**Final solution**:

> INTERNET (tailless seabird = TER(N), incessant tennis = TENNI(S), "return" means put it backwards before inserting TER; "web" as def)

Comment: @Silenus Unless just "web" is the definition.

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Comment: I believe I know the solution to the final clue...

Comment: @Silenus As do I

Comment: @Silenus Something to do with "web" as in internet?

Comment: Yes, and a ter(n) is a type of seabird.

Comment: Just to be clear - this was the first answer with the final solution, right?

Comment: @Matt I think Silenus was the first to get the correct *word* but I was the first to get the correct *explanation* for the final metacryptic solution. It was a team effort :-)

Comment: @Silenus [was first with the word](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/47846/4) but not a full derivation as a word was missing from the meta-clue at that time.  THIS answer was first to get it from the puzzle and not from inferring the missing part.

Comment: Sorry @Silenus but I'm going to give the tick to rand al'thor because he was first with the solution, and I did include "create the final clue" in the instructions.

Comment: @Matt, fine by me!

Answer (score 7):

**Partial Answer**

1.

> **TAILLESS** (ILL[sick] inside TA ESS[SEATS*]; [def] amputation)

2.

> **SEABIRD** ([def] fowl; BARSIDE*)

7.

> **WEB** (W.E.B.[Du Bois]; [def] woven silk])

The final clue is:

> Tailless seabird trapped in incessant tennis return web (8)

And its answer is

> **INTERNET** (TER(n)[seabird] inserted in[trapped in] IN NET[tenni(s)<]; [def] web)

Comment: "incessant tennis" is tennis without the end: "TENNI".  Reversing it will give you what you need.  So the missing word must clue reversing (or anagramming).

Comment: I have a better explanation for the metacryptic: "incessant tennis" = TENNI.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain But I put it into my *answer* before your comment :-)

Answer (score 7):

### Partial answer

Chaotic print aped captured preposition (7, 2)

> printaped* = TRAPPED IN

Center of Liechtenstein and Nicaragua's lovely sport (6)

> Liech(ten)stein + Ni's = TENNIS

Play tune with two helpings of rosemary, first get refund (6)

> tunerr* = RETURN